# Tramsaction taking long, 1 part is spent

Tags: blockchain

So i made a transaction today:

https://blockchain.info/tx/1eab828a3e673e322aa4da4ff03962dbad3b2fa5b70818e3db9c5dc32abead93

Besides the fact that this is taking ages, 1 of them has the state 'spent'. I am missing some informatioon on this. Could someone explain this? And why is the rest unspent?

Comment: I am one of the people in your block right now and trying to figure out why were stuck. I paid for a transaction accelerator just now for our transaction so hopefully that resolves the issue

Comment: Did you withdraw your bitcoin from CEX.IO to Binance? Trying to narrow down the problem

Comment: no, gdax. I have the feeling that we shouldn't touch it anymore, so it will be dropped from the mempool, and will eventually will get back to your wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some exchanges combine many transactions into a single transaction when withdrawing, to save fees and be more efficient with space. It will likely confirm eventually, you'll just have to wait for a miner to put it in a block. One output could be spent already because it is possible to spend from unconfirmed outputs, just slightly more risky.

See also: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)